# L1 cache vs Main memory

Tags: caching, memory, cycle, cpu-architecture

How many cycles does it take to access the L1 cache and main memory
i know it is dependent.

if L1, L2, L3 are missed, how many cycles does it take to access main memory ?

but i want to know approximate average cycles.

Comment: There is no direct answer, it depends from chip to chip. You need to read the fact sheet of the chip you are interested in.

Comment: for example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333547/cache-specifications-for-intel-core-i7/20354270#20354270

Answer (score 2):

[Latency Numbers Every Programmer Should Know](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832). [Plotted over time](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~rcs/research/interactive_latency.html).